# html how to remove the empty space in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i manage to do insert a link into iframe , but when i insert the link there is the empty space there, how to remove this, any suggestion to solve this problem
[image]

this is my code

```
<iframe src="http://insage.com.my/ir/cmn/trps02/masanews_ir.aspx?Symbol=5242" style="border:1px #123 none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="1600px" width="1000px" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Maybe it's because it's the design of the link

Comment: thanks you , is there any html syntax can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web page you have inserted in the iframe uses **Bootstrap**. The class 'container' in bootstrap has rules to centrally align the content inside this class accordingly to the width specified. **Good Web aesthetics**.

So when you open the page on browser, you will see the width of 1170px and entire content centrally aligned.
And as you have specified the width of 1000px for the iFrame, it will take the width of 970px.

If you still wish to remove the space though **not recommended**. You will have to override the rules of the 'container' class and adjust the width of iframe to fall in either 970px or 1170px or other grids specified in the bootstrap framework.

```
.container {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Also, **iFrames are now obselete**.